# .each of jquery issue

Tags: jquery, each

in my function in a jquery, i try to split a long string. i think that when splitting, the result is an array. so i used .each to get the values of splitted string. however, it is not showing anything. where is my error in this syntax:

```
 function DisplayList(data) {
    $.each(data.split('|'), function (index, value) {
        $(".listDisplay").html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
    });
 };
```

when i put index in the .html() instead of value, i am shown the number of elements in the array. it's supposed to show something like [0], [1], [2]... right?

what i really want is to show in a paragraph form the contents of my splitted string... (.listDisplay is a div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
$(".listDisplay").html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
```

overwrites the contents of ".listDisplay" with the current `value`. So each iteration of the `$.each()` overwrites the previous value and then when the `$.each()` finishes ".listDisplay" will hold whatever `value` was from the final iteration.

Try changing it to:

```
$(".listDisplay").append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
```

That will add a new paragraph to the end of ".listDisplay" rather than overwriting the existing contents. So the `.each()` will add a new paragraph for each item in the array returned by `data.split('|')`.

(You may want to add `$(".listDisplay").empty()` or `$(".listDisplay").html("")` just before the `$.each()` to clear any existing contents in your div before adding the new paragraphs.)

Another approach is to do it in one line without the `$.each()`:

```
function DisplayList(data) {
   $(".listDisplay").html('<p>' + data.replace(/\|/g, '</p><p>') + '</p>');
};
```

Comment: my god, thank you... never heard of .append before... actually, i use this on the onselect event of a datepicker. so everytime the user, select a date, a new list is generated. however, i think it will all append the results of json everytime i change a date. how do i clear .listDisplay?

Comment: Building a string like in Matthew's answer is likely more efficient than calling `.append()` repeatedly. I've updated my answer to mention a couple of ways to clear the div, and also to show a way to do it without using `$.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

That will only show the last value.

```
function DisplayList(data) {
    var html = '';
    $.each(data.split('|'), function (index, value) {
        html += '<p>' + value + '</p>';
    });

    $(".listDisplay").html(html);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular for loop with the append method...

```
var dataArr = data.split('|'),
    list = $(".listDisplay");

list.empty(); // This will clear the list first.
for (var i = 0, len = dataArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    list.append('<p>' + dataArr[i] + '</p>');
}
```